# Salesforce for outlook

Tags: salesforce-for-outlook

I am not getting an option to install salesforce for outlook in my Orgs. When I enter Salesforce for Outlook in the Quick Find box, I don't get anything. I have tried that in both my personal orgs as well as the Sandboxes.

Comment: Have you downloaded the app?

Comment: I am not getting an option to download the app.When i enter Salesforce for Outlook in the Quick Find box, i don't get anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're just looking in the wrong place. To download Salesforce for Outlook, whilst logged into Salesforce:

> Your Username > My Settings > Download Now

You'll be able to install it and sign in to it from there.

[image]