# Salesforce for outlook?

Tags: outlook

Do they still make a non office 365 version for Salesforce outlook? I've seen documentation on the Salesforce website referring to the Salesforce for Outlook tool with Winter 17, but I cannot find the install section in the quick finder search bar. I have a client that is looking to integrate Salesforce for Outlook, but does not use O365.

Is this still around? Or am I just missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Just found this by looking on this post [Salesforce for outlook](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/133887/salesforce-for-outlook)

They really need to update the Salesforce documentation!